# Simplify solution set of a system of equations with parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let's say I have a system of linear equations with a free variable which has a solution set that looks like this:

$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{11}{5}\\\frac{3}{5}\\0\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{3}{5}\\\frac{1}{5}\\1\end{pmatrix}t\right\}
$$

with $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

My question is if I can "simplify" the vectors in the solution set in any way, by multiplying the vectors horizontally or vertically to remove the denominator $5$. Is it possible? Can I only multiply by $5$ the vector which is muliplied by the parameter?

I know that given an invertible square matrix $A$ and the system $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$, there exists a unique solution $x=A^{-1}\vec{b})$. Can this help me with this question?

I think I've seen textbooks simplify when it comes to the basis of a subspace, but I'm not sure about solution sets with a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    x\\y\\z
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1\\1\\2
  \end{pmatrix}
  +
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -3\\1\\5
  \end{pmatrix}
  s$$
where $s=(t-2)/5$.

Comment: How did $0$ first vector, last row become a $2$?

Comment: I changed it to 2, I think that's right? Sorry for the edits, I tried to do it without pen and paper and made mistakes!

Comment: Thank you, I think it's correct. I just don't know the thought process behind, so basically it's okay to multiply the vectors by scalars?

Comment: Absolutely! It is the one of the two operations defined in a vector space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition

Comment: The second vector was multiplied by 5, what about the first vector?

Comment: The second vector was multiplied by 5 because the associated scalar was divided by 5. But before that we subtracted 2, and that is what affects the first vector. For the intermediate step we might write $
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x\\y\\z
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\1 \\2
  \end{pmatrix}
  +
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -3/5 \\1/5 \\1
  \end{pmatrix}
  r
$
where
$r=t-2$

Comment: Think about it this way: your solution space is a line, specified by a point (the first vector) and a direction (the second). You can scale the direction, and you can choose a "nice" point on the line. You're not guaranteed to be able to find an integer point as in this nice example, though.

Comment: Thank you so much for the intuition @dbx!